# How do get Firefox to display ASCII control code charachters 0-31 as font glyphs 0-31?

Tags: firefox, encoding, fonts, ascii, glyph

I am using a .ttf font ( _decterm.ttf ) that is loaded with CSS:
@font-face { font-family: "DEC";       src: url("FONTS/_decterm.ttf")        format("truetype"); }
It has usable glyphs in slots 0-31.

ASCII characters 0-31 ( in the HTML )  do not display , even when using the  & # 00 ; � format.

LOL ( This editor shows a replacement for ASCII 0 above , I had to space it out so that it would not replace it. )

The font I am using has glyphs for characters 0-31.
Maybe there is a way to remap the encodings for 0-31?

Here is 0-31...

���������
�
������������������

I do not even get this displayed in the browser window.  I get one of them.

I suspect that Firefox is dropping ASCII codes 0-31. I would like to see Firefox dislpay them just like ASCII codes 32-127.

Comment: ASCII characters 0 to 31 (and 127) are control codes: they have no graphical representation. On modern fonts, glyph number is an internal implementation detail not related to any ASCII or Unicode code point (but there is a map). So, if you uses a modern font, just find the character in Unicode, and use it. Font will remap to your "0-31 characters". If you are using an old font (e.g. bitmaps of *retro-*computers), you need special libraries (you do not want that all complex text functions will mangle the text, as expected on normal text).

Comment: So: it is impossible to answer your question: it lacks of details (e.g. which font, how do you use the font, what are the expected characters (there is not single way to represent such characters, Commodore 64, DOS, Teletext, etc. used different characters).

Comment: You are using a TTF so it uses Unicode code points (forget about glyph slots, these are internal implementation of font, it doesn't matter for users, and you cannot easily access slots numbers). So, you have a Unicode font, which probably will encode codepoints 0 to 31 into glyphs. But HTML handles control codes differently (also because security implications). So I think you should do as other program do: internally you should convert the bytes 0 to 31 into proper Unicode code point for such glyphs. Check if your font has documentation and aliases for that.

Comment: The glyph's I want to display reside at U+0 thru U+31.  What I want to do is ,  tell the browser to just display U+0-U+31  when it receives those codes.  The font is a recreation of the raster font built into a 7-bit DEC terminal.  The glyph's at ASCII  0-31 are actual glyph's that were displayed on the terminal when those codes were received.  I just want to reproduce that display.  I think you are proposing that I copy the glyph's into a different position in font ( unicode map ) ex:U+x thru U+X+31 , and then add X to the unicode value of all characters in documents before I view them.